# Where are archived Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I accidentally clicked "Archive Link" in Dynamic Links. But the link was already  distributed so can't be changed. How can I find it or entry the same one?
https://console.firebase.google.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to EDIT a Dynamic Link that has been archived, consider this:

1. You need to know the Dynamic Link in question
2. Using Firebase Console, click to edit some other (non archived) Dynamic Link.
3. Note the shortened URL itself, and see how it is represented in the address in the browser address bar, specifically the end of the URL
4. Simply replace the non-archived shortened URL at end of the URL, with that of the ARCHIVED shortened URL, and load it (hit enter).

---

Result: You will be presented with the edit screen for that archived dynamic URL.
This worked for me today: 10/25/2019

Comment: You are lifesaver. Still working in 2021
Thank you

Comment: You could unarchive the dynamic link making a POST to the Firebase API. 
For that, go to Firebase Console -> Dynamic Links and copy the headers of a POST request.

After that, do a request with the previous headers and your archived link and project, like:

curl 'https://firebasedurablelinks-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/updateDurableLink'
--data-raw '{"durableLink":{"shortDurableLink":{"link":"ARCHIVED_LINK"}},"newDurableLink":{"shortDurableLink":{"visibility":"UNARCHIVED"}},"newDurableLinkMask":"short_durable_link","projectInfo":{"projectNumber":"PROJECT_NUMBER"}}' \
--compressed

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me in 2022. After updating the URL I'm getting an error "There was an unknown error while processing the request."

Comment: it worked correctly for me in 2022!

Answer (score 2):

What solved it to me was to do a HTTP request similar to the one that is done when archiving a register in the dynamic links page, but setting the status to "UNARCHIVED" rather than "ARCHIVED". I did it by using the `fetch` API directly in the chrome developer tools and worked great!

Here are the steps:

- Go to the dynamic links page and create an example link (ex: `yourdomain.page.link/test-page`;
- Open the developer tools on the Network tab;
- Delete the recently created example link (test-page) and localize the request record generated in the Network tab. There's a POST **request** there;
- Click with the right button upon this record and copy it as a fetch request;
- Paste it in some text editor and find and replace 2 things: the "test-page" value and the status value "ARCHIVED" to "UNARCHIVED" (in everywhere you find it);
- Finally, go back to the developer tools and paste the fetch request in the "Console" tab and press "Enter" on your keyboard. If the request run without errors, probably you'll see your record back to the list =)

Answer (score 1):

Surprised up to this writing Google hasn't provide functionality for this.
In any case I was able to unarchive my short link by getting the CURL POST from Charles proxy. I archived an active link, and then clicked undo, then copied the post request made and changed the JSON body to my archived link.

```
curl 
-H "Host: firebasedurablelinks-pa.clients6.google.com" 
-H "Cookie: XXXX" 
-H "sec-ch-ua: \"Google Chrome\";v=\"107\", \"Chromium\";v=\"107\", \"Not=A?Brand\";v=\"24\"" 
-H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: XXX" 
-H "authorization: XXXX" 
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 
-H "content-type: application/json" 
-H "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" 
-H "x-goog-authuser: 0" -H "sec-ch-ua-platform: \"macOS\"" 
-H "origin: https://console.firebase.google.com" 
-H "x-client-data: XXXX" 
-H "sec-fetch-site: same-site" 
-H "sec-fetch-mode: cors"
-H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" 
-H "referer: https://console.firebase.google.com/" 
-H "accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" 
--data-binary "{\"durableLink\":{\"shortDurableLink\":{\"link\":\"THE_ARCHIVED_LINK"}},\"newDurableLink\":{\"shortDurableLink\":{\"visibility\":\"UNARCHIVED\"}},\"newDurableLinkMask\":\"short_durable_link\",\"projectInfo\":{\"projectNumber\":\"PROJECT_NUMBER\"}}" 
--compressed "https://firebasedurablelinks-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/updateDurableLink?alt=json&key=XXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is currently possible to get a list of archived links. You might want to [file a bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that.

But your link will continue to work. Archiving it merely removes it from the console. So I'd create a new link for same destination, and just phase out the old one (knowing that it will continue to work).

Comment: I sent a request about restoring archived Links. And got an answer that they are working on it but can't provide any details or timelines at this time.